# Two jQuery buttons on the same page don't work

Tags: jquery

I added jQuery on/off button to my SMOF framework but I have little error here http://www.screenr.com/q8l8

https://gist.github.com/2973585 (jquery.iphone-switch)

(www) gist.github.com/2973599 (myjs.js)

Thx for your time and all advices

Comment: Please post relevant code samples here instead of requiring users to visit external webpages to determine what code is relevent to your issue.  In addition, please update your question to explain what exactly is the problem.

Comment: Code will be more helpful than a mute video.

Comment: You should not post external links, but rather try to briefly explain your problem and post some useful code snippets.

Answer (score 0):

Easy! The problem is in your HTML. You need different ids on your two input elements.

Comment: but my input elements have different id's

Comment: Ok - it was hard to tell from the video. Can you post your HTML as a gist and I'll look at it again?